# Jython: include custom java class [oanda]

Tags: java, jython

```
  >>> import sys
  >>> sys.path.append("/usr/local/oanda_fxtrade.jar") # add the jar to your path
   >>> 
  >>> import com.oanda.fxtrade.api.test.Example1 as main1
  >>> import com.oanda.fxtrade.api.test.Example2 as cancel
  main1("JPY",9,'-1')
  TypeError: main1("JPY",9,'-1'): expected 0 args; got 3
```

This seems no error - but really i need some args

cancel()
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]

Inside java class

```
  public final class Example1 extends Thread {
  private Example1() {
        super();
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
FXClient fxclient  = API.createFXGame();

String username = "foo";
String password = "foo";
String sel=args[0];
String str1=args[1];
    String str2=args[2];
```

main1.main("JPY 9 -1")

TypeError: main(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String[]

Ok I think I went to the next level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
import com.oanda.fxtrade.api.test.Example1 as main1
```

main1 is the class.  In java executing the class will run main but that doesn't mean you can pass args to the class.

Try:

```
main1.main(["JPY","9","-1"])
```

**EDIT:**
There were two separate issues here.

For the subsequent error `Could not initialize class com.oanda.fxtrade.api.API`... it looks like you should review this question: [Why does Jython refuse to find my Java package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681849/why-does-jython-refuse-to-find-my-java-package)

calling sys.path.append to add the jar does not allow the package scanner operate which happens at load time.  You should try either importing the required modules/classes manually or perhaps adding the jar to the **CLASSPATH** before invoking jython.

from here I think the jython answer is in and it becomes a *com.oanda.fxtrade.api* question with is probably outside SO scope.

Comment: `main1()` tries to create an instance of Example1 class, it won't run `main()`.

Comment: oops, right this is not being run from the command line. I should have tested whether it takes `main1().main("args","go","here")` but I don't have the oanda jars here.

Comment: `array=[ 0 for w in range(3)];
    array=['JPY','9','-1'];
    main1.main(array)`

Comment: TypeError: main(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String[]
Ok I think I went to the next level