# Packaging a Jython program in an executable jar

Tags: jython, packaging, executable-jar

I am trying to package a jython program into an executable jar which the user can simply double-click to run without installing jython ahead of time. Ultimately, I would like to include an additional library which I wrote with the jar, but at the moment I am just trying to package a simple program and have it run from the jar.

I have tried following the jar instructions in the "Using the Jar Method" section here: [Jython FAQ: Using the Jar Method](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts#Using_the_Jar_Method)

I have also looked at slides 25-28 here: [Jython Update 2012 slides](http://www.slideshare.net/fwierzbicki/jython-update-2012#)

And finally here:
[stackoverflow Question: Distributing My Python Scripts as Jars with Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252965/distributing-my-python-scripts-as-jars-with-jython)

I have installed jython 2.5.3, jvm 1.6, and python 2.7.3 on my mac which is running OS X 10.8.3.

These are the steps I go through to create the jar and run it:

1. Create a copy of jython.jar from my jython installation directory.
2. `zip -r jython_copy.jar Lib` (where Lib is the folder in the jython installation directory)
3. `cp myJythonProgram.py __run__.py` (myJythonProgram.py does not include an 'if **name** == **main**' line)
4. `zip jython_copy.jar __run__.py`
5. `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/my/app/jython_copy.jar:$CLASSPATH`

I have tried running the jar using all three of these methods:

1. `java org.python.util.jython -jar myapp.jar`
2. `java -cp myapp.jar org.python.util.jython -jar myapp.jar`
3. `java -jar myapp.jar -jar myapp.jar`

This works if my program doesn't use any import statements.

However I am running into an issue where some python packages are not able to be found when I run the jar. For instance, I get the error "ImportError: No module named random" when I include the line `from random import random` in my program. No errors occur on lines in the program when I import from javax.swing, java.awt, time, or math.

Additionally, I tried to package a jar with my library and a jython program which imports my library using the previous steps as well as the following additional steps:

1. `zip jython_copy.jar myLibrary.jar`
2. `jar ufm jython_copy.jar othermanifest.mf`

othermanifest.mf only contains the line `Class-Path: ./myLibrary.jar`.

This too gives the error "ImportError: No module named myLibrary"

I would appreciate any insight into what I am doing incorrectly or other steps I should take.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the Maven Jython plugin mentioned at http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts#Using_Maven ?

Comment: No not yet, but if I can't get this method to work then that is my next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized what the problem was and I wanted to document it in case anyone else has the same problems.

I was using the jython.jar file that came in the standard installation of Jython, and NOT the standalone jython.jar (the instructions at [Using the Jar Method](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts#Using_the_Jar_Method) mentions this, but the instructions at [Building Jars](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts#Building_jars_-_some_samples) do not). I am still unsure why copying the Lib/ folder of the standard installation into the jython.jar that came with that installation didn't work on my system. However, once I used the standalone jar, things started to work more smoothly.

Additionally, I was able to get my library to work with the packaged file by doing three things in addition to the steps I laid out in my question:

1. Exploding the standalone jython.jar and copying the folder with all of my library files into Lib, then create a new jar. This seemed to be the easiest way to include my library and allows me to package everything into a single jar.
2. I discovered after reading Frank Wierzbicki's answer in [Why does Jython refuse to find my Java package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681849/why-does-jython-refuse-to-find-my-java-package) that because I am now using the standalone jar, I could no longer use imports of the style `from java.awt import *`, instead I needed to fully specify each thing I was importing, for example `from java.awt.Font import PLAIN, BOLD, ITALIC`. So I went through the library's imports and fixed the few that were of the wrong style.
3. Now that I am adding my Library directly to the Jar's Lib folder, instead of writing `Class-Path: ./myLibrary.jar` in `othermanifest.mf`, I put `Main-Class: org.python.util.JarRunner` as per Frank Wierzbicki's answer in the post I mentioned in my question: [Distributing my Python scripts as JAR files with Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252965/distributing-my-python-scripts-as-jars-with-jython)

This allowed me to create a double-clickable executable jar containing my library and jython file that I wanted to run.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions. They both work, but one better than the other.

I believe you can rename your python script as `__run__.py`, place that file inside the .jar file, and pass the .jar file through a python interpreter.  See https://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#invoking-the-jython-interpreter for more.

Multiple methods to run Jython from the java code while running through JVM are described [here,](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#using-jython-within-java-applications) at the Jython documentation.

EDIT:

You can execute a command line code that runs the python file you want.
[Link to an example of running command line code from java here.](http://www.linglom.com/programming/java/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/)