# Access a python file in a jython jar from Eclipse?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jar, jython

I'm currently working on a project involve Java and Python. Long story short, I followed some [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701979/packaging-a-jython-program-in-an-executable-jar) on ways to access Python file from Java by packaging the file into a jython jar and import into the Java project.

Instead of using "java -jar jython.jar **run**.py" to call the **run**.py, anybody know if there is way to call the file from Eclipse (assuming I already add the jython.jar into to my build path?

Thank you so much!

Comment: William, I know we've already gone through this, but I think my answer below will really help you.

Comment: How is this William, below?

Comment: Be sure to mark solution below as answer.

Comment: Hello Malik, thank you for the screenshot and explanation. Now, the test.py file is in the source folder NOT in the jar that I important. What if I packaged it in the jython.jar? Can you still call it?

Comment: Why would you do this, if possible? Right click your project in Eclipse and export. You can then export to a runnable JAR that can contain your entire project including both of those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag this image in the entry bar in your browser. The `PythonInterpreter` executes `test.py`.

[image: Jython]

Comment: How is this William? I've tried you walk you through completely.

Comment: Hello Malik, really appreciate you spend time on explaining this. I know how to add jar to build path and use jython jar. My real question is, I have package a python file in the jar, say print hello world, it's not part of the jython.jar. Through command line I can do this "java -jar jython.jar print.py" and it will call the python. Now I want to know how to do this in Eclipse...Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I believe so but why would you package `script.py` in `jython.jar`? You can export your whole Eclipse project to a jar as is.

Comment: Yes, but in your case, if you export your project to a jar, you won't be able to call test.py anymore because test.py will be in a zip file, your src/test.py won't work.

Comment: I think it will work `src/test.py` will just be contained within the JAR.

Comment: I just tested and it is not working. That's exactly where my question come from. Let's say if python code can directly called by a Java in a jar (both files are in the same jar) then I would'n even need to package it anywhere.

Comment: Then place the python file out of the project and use a relative path.

Comment: The python script contains the algorithm of the engine, I'm trying to discover a way to hide the code while be able to call the function.

Comment: Then place the python file out of the project and use a relative path. Make the python file a hidden file so that no one has to see it.

Comment: Sure, then see you around I guess.