# How to execute if statement using Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
public class JythonTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
    interp.exec("if 2 > 1:");
    interp.exec("   print('in if statement!'");
}
}
```

I need to be able to execute Python code from a Java program, so decided to try out Jython, but I'm unfamiliar with it. I tried executing the above code, but got the error: "Exception in thread "main" SyntaxError: ("mismatched input '' expecting INDENT", ('', 1, 9, 'if 2 > 1:\n'))". Any ideas what this means or how I can otherwise execute an if statement using the PythonInterpreter?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Yep I am using Eclipse!

Comment: I have a suggestion for you just hold on a second while I post another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionals must be entered as a single string and you have an extra parenthesis:

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class JythonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
        interp.exec("if 2 > 1: print 'in if statement!'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than executing a script line by line with strings you can invoke the interpreter to run a file. All you have to do is provide a file path to your python file, in this example place `script.py` in the `src` folder.

`script.py`

```
if 2 > 1:
    print 'in if statement'
```

`JythonTest.java`

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class JythonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
        interp.execfile("src/script.py");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you add a new answer instead of editing it into your existing one?

Comment: Because they're two separate ideas. Why do you think stack exchange would add such a feature?

Comment: If I do this, will I be able to input to the program whilst it is running e.g for a python program like this:
`name=raw_input()
print('Hi '+name)`
If so, how?

Comment: Just tried the following code: [link](http://pastebin.com/xUwfsRcw)
And got the error: Exception in thread "main" SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input '='", ('test1.py', 1, 10, 'print(name=raw_input()\n'))".

Comment: That's not even proper python. You have two statement in a print statement.

Comment: Woops sorry just put 'print' in the wrong place. Should be: `out.write("name=raw_input()\nprint('Hi '+name)");`
When I run that, nothing happens. Think it just gets stuck waiting for the input. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, why write the python programmatically? Why don't you just type it yourself and place it in the folder as I described.

Comment: Did you put the python file in the source folder and call `interp.execfile("src/script.py")`?

Comment: See one of my previous answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120716/access-a-python-file-in-a-jython-jar-from-eclipse/28120725#28120725).

Comment: That doesn't help with this I'm afraid. I just need a way to give arguments to the PythonInterpreter. I've just seen that PythonInterpreter has a setOut() method, which looks like it could do the trick, but I'm not sure how to use it. Do you know how I can? Thanks for all your help btw!

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Please see my last question^

Comment: I'm sorry Louis. I have no idea about the `setOut` method, I'm just as unfamiliar with Jython as you are.