# Hadoop Streaming using python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to execute the map reduce code as below:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/Hadoop/Hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar –file mapper.py –mapper mapper.py –file reducer.py – reducer reducer.py –input /user/training/samplypy.txt –ouput  /user/training/pythonMR/output
```

getting below exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: –file
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

I am using Hadoop 1.0.3. I've tried with multiple versions of hadoop-streaming jar like:

```
hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar 
hadoop-streaming-1.2.0.jar 
hadoop-streaming.jar
```

Comment: Where is the document that tells you to run these command?

Comment: Have you got your `$HADOOP_HOME` env variable set?

Comment: Refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701979/packaging-a-jython-program-in-an-executable-jar.

Answer (score 1):

1. One thing I can tell is that you did not use full path for '-file' statement:

   –file /mapper/location/mapper.py (use full path with the file name here)

   –mapper mapper.py (correct, mapper file name only)

   –file /reducer/location/reducer.py (use full path with the file name here)

   – reducer reducer.py (correct, reducer file name only)
2. make sure your -input and -output are pointing to HDFS not local path

Here is the code I used:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=15 -D stream.map.input.field.separator=',' -D stream.map.output.field.separator=',' \
-D mapred.textoutputformat.separator=',' \
-input /user/temp/in/ \
-output /user/temp/out \
-file  /app/qa/python/mapper.py \
-mapper mapper.py \
-file  /app/qa/python/reducer.py \
-reducer reducer.py
```